# docusign-python-api error: PARTNER_AUTHENTICATION_FAILED

Tags: python, oauth, docusignapi

**I can't authorize with docusign-python-api, wondering if anyone could help me figure out why I can't.**

So the picture is my API key from the Admin>Api and Keys, as you can see, there is an error. I don't know what that means, where that came from.

[image]

I am trying to use the docusign-python-client (with python3)

https://github.com/docusign/docusign-python-client

after pip installing it I just ran the script under **Usage** in the readme, and on the line:

```
login_info = auth_api.login(api_password='true', include_account_id_guid='true')
```

I get the following error :

```
Exception when calling DocuSign API: (401)
Reason: Unauthorized
HTTP response headers: HTTPHeaderDict({'Cache-Control': 'no-cache', 'Content-Length': '165', 'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8', 'X-DocuSign-TraceToken': '8cbbb3f9-2fb1-450e-a03e-ecf180e599b5', 'Date': 'Thu, 17 Jan 2019 17:09:12 GMT', 'Vary': 'Accept-Encoding', 'Strict-Transport-Security': 'max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains'})
HTTP response body: b'{\r\n  "errorCode": "PARTNER_AUTHENTICATION_FAILED",\r\n  "message": "The specified Integrator Key was not found or is disabled. An Integrator key was not specified."\r\n}'
```

My credentials are:

```
integrator_key = e89c2480-6dd8-4f38-9787-08ee5ecf4407#Integrator key from image
base_url = "https://demo.docusign.net/restapi"
oauth_base_url = "account-d.docusign.com" # use account.docusign.com for Live/Production
redirect_uri = "https://www.docusign.com/api" #didn't change, so doesn't match my callback uri in image
private_key_filename = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "keys/docusign_private_key.txt") #I commented out the line that uses this
user_id = my.name@mycompany.com #email I use to login to docusign
```

Once again, i do not use private_key_filename because I commented out the line

```
api_client.configure_jwt_authorization_flow(private_key_filename, oauth_base_url, integrator_key, user_id, 3600)
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your application one where the user will be present? If so, please try out the new [Python code example launcher](https://github.com/docusign/eg-03-python-auth-code-grant). It uses oauth authorization code grant.

If there won't be a user available to login, then you're creating a Service Integration. In that case, you need to create a key pair for the Integration Key and provide the private key to your app. An example of this type of app is the [eg-01-python-jwt](https://github.com/docusign/eg-01-python-jwt) example. Please start with it for JWT authentication.

### Added: Custom Fields for Retrieve

Envelope Custom Fields optionally store *metadata* for an envelope. They're commonly used to categorize envelopes and to store data about an envelope in a machine-readable format that won't be seen by the signer(s) or any other recipients.

Envelope Custom Fields can be added via the DocuSign Web Tool. See this [help topic.](https://support.docusign.com/guides/ndse-admin-guide-document-labels)

You can also add them programmatically via the API. See the [EnvelopeCustomFields](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Envelopes/EnvelopeCustomFields) API resource.

#### Use cases

Typically, if envelopes will be sent from the DocuSign web tool, then the sender can also use the web tool to set the envelope's custom fields. Custom Fields can be created/configured as required and as drop-down select fields to help with data integrity issues.

If an API integration application is creating the envelopes on behalf of the sender, then the application should usually also set the custom fields when the envelope is created. Custom field values can be included in the Envelopes::create API call, or can be added later via the EnvelopeCustomFields API resource.

Comment: Thanks for the links, I will check them out, but since it sounds like you know what you are talking about: the reason I am doing all of this is just because we want to have a pre-populated, read-only field in the form that we can pull as one of the custom fields when we copy files using a tool called DocusignRetrieve. After not the most thorough investigation, I got it into my head that API is the way to do this. Do you know if there is an easier way? And if not, am I describing a Service Integration (should I go with your latter option)?

Comment: Hi Larry, I tried both of these. With eg-01-jwt, I got  Error response: {"error":"invalid_grant"} but it's like deep in cryptography library error, some openssl error code 108 ASN1_R_CIPHER_HAS_NO_OBJECT_IDENTIFIER. I have no idea what that is, so on to eg-03-python-auth-code-grant. I have the flask app up and running, but there is not much information on how to set up the ds_config file, **can you please explain what each variable should be**, as I get redirected to login with message 'The redirect URI is not registered properly with DocuSign' every time I try and call one of the controllers

Comment: Hi @amchugh89, Sorry you're having a problem. I've added some more info to the ds_config file and the Readme. See this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eiRI4fe5HgM) for info on creating a client id (an Integration Key). If you have more questions on getting the example running, please open a new question in StackOverflow. Thank you.

Comment: Hi @amchugh89, I have added info about Custom Fields to my answer, see above. Please open a new StackOverflow question if you have further questions

Comment: Thank you, I will look at this. i started to make progress with Postman calls, but I think the way Postman authenticates is completely different, so after I refresh on this, I might ask another ELI5-type question about the diff types of auth.