# Cannot create an Integrator Key Docusign

Tags: docusignapi

I kept getting the following error when using Docusign python API

**The specified Integrator Key was not found or is disabled. An Integrator key was not specified**

```
Exception when calling DocuSign API: (401)
Reason: Unauthorized
HTTP response headers: HTTPHeaderDict({'Cache-Control': 'no-cache', 'Content-Length': '165', 'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8', 'X-DocuSign-TraceToken': '2818f346-79f7-4c81-a1e1-b8da0f5556a6', 'Date': 'Thu, 17 Jan 2019 17:52:40 GMT', 'Vary': 'Accept-Encoding', 'Strict-Transport-Security': 'max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains'})
HTTP response body: b'{\r\n  "errorCode": "PARTNER_AUTHENTICATION_FAILED",\r\n  "message": "The specified Integrator Key was not found or is disabled. An Integrator key was not specified."\r\n}'
```

So I tried creating new Integrator keys, not really knowing what the callback URI should be or much about what I am doing.

I noticed that everytime I created a key, if I refreshed browser, status would go to 'Error' - anybody know how I can generate an Integrator Key that stays in status 'Demo' and that i can use to make API calls

[image]

Here is an example of how I am setting up integrator key:

[image]

---

**EDIT**

I created a new sandbox of my own, when I create an API key in there it doesn't go to Error, stays in status 'Demo'

API key config looks like

[image]

and code to call looks like

```
integrator_key = MY_KEY_FROM_SCREENSHOT
base_url = "https://demo.docusign.net/restapi"
oauth_base_url = 'account-d.docusign.com'
redirect_uri = 'http://localhost:8000'
user_id = MY_EMAIL


#NOTHING HERE REALLY
private_key_filename = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "keys/docusign_private_key.txt")

oauth_login_url = api_client.get_jwt_uri(integrator_key, redirect_uri, oauth_base_url)
# configure the ApiClient to asynchronously get an access token and store it
#api_client.configure_jwt_authorization_flow(private_key_filename, oauth_base_url, integrator_key, user_id, 3600)
docusign.configuration.api_client = api_client
auth_api = AuthenticationApi()
try:
    login_info = auth_api.login(api_password='true', include_account_id_guid='true')
```

Comment: The error in the URL contains "An Integrator key was not specified". Can you elaborate on how you're performing the API call / authentication?

Comment: I am using values from Admin>API Key, where I set a description, Integrator key is auto-generated, andfor the callback URI I set http://127.0.0.1:8000/tools/ds_api (8000 is django port, I am running a django app and have created a url in urls.py although I am not sure that is the issue). I am getting an 'Error' (screenshot) BEFORE even running the API that generates the error (codeblock), so I do not think that my inability to create API creds has anything to do with the API call, but call here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54241334/docusign-python-api-error-partner-authentication-failed

Comment: So I just created a new one with the callback uri "http://localhost:8000" as specified in video https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=eiRI4fe5HgM and as soon as I refresh page (not even calling API or anything else), the entry goes from Demo to Error. i think maybe this is from trying too many times or because I lack permissions to use API or something

Comment: I'd recommend opening a case with DocuSign Support (https://support.docusign.com/). Include your demo account ID and at least one of the integrator keys that's switched over to 'error'

Comment: Sorry you're having these problems. Please EDIT your question to show how you're calling DocuSign.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [docusign-python-api error: PARTNER\_AUTHENTICATION\_FAILED](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54241334/docusign-python-api-error-partner-authentication-failed)

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm I don't know why the Integration Key's status is changing to "Error."

A couple of ideas:

1. When adding a Redirect URI, include `http://` or `https://` at the start of the URI. Eg, enter `http://127.0.0.1:8000/tools/ds_api`
2. Don't click the `Review Transactions` option of the `Actions` drop down. That should only be done when you are ready for the Go-Live test.

Comment: I had http:// in there, the markup just converts it. I will stop reviewing transactions though